# Detect first zero from string in php

Tags: php

```
function number_check($int){
    if($int>0 && !is_float($int)){return TRUE;}
    else{return FALSE;}
}

$var="025";

if(number_check($var)){echo "pass";}else{echo "fail";}
```

I have make a function to check the number for post id.

`post_id` should always `> 0` and no decimal.

but I have a problem when user try to enter `000243`, if user put `zero` at front, it return `true`.

Is any way to solve this?

Comment: Is 000243 not correct then, as it is technically a number above 0?

Comment: it should return true, right ?! this is what you're code does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think checking `$int{0} != 0` will solve what you are trying to achieve :

```
function number_check($int){
    if ( $int > 0 && !is_float($int) && $int{0} != 0 ) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

$var="023";

if ( number_check($var) ) {
    echo "pass";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

Check this [**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/YL1pimFi)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<?php
echo intval('000243');
?>
```

Comment: i try echo intval(025); it return 21 not 25

Comment: @BenWong As it is an octal number it has to return 21! Do you want to get rid of the starting zeroes?

Comment: `echo intval(025);` !== `echo intval('025');`

Comment: is any way to check and return true or false, im actually try to check it only

Answer (score 1):

try to assign value to $var without using quotes.
i.e $var = 000243;

Comment: If you echo $var, after assigning it as `$var = 000243;`, what would you expect to see, and what do you actually see?

Comment: He gets this value form user ( probably via `$_POST`), it's not hardcoded value.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do that is the following:

```
function prepareID($id)
{
    $id = preg_replace('/^([0]*)/', '', $id);

    return (int)$id;
}

$var = prepareID("025");
```

The prepareID function will remove any leading zeros and it will return an integer

Comment: Do not rewrite existing functions. `ltrim($id, '0')`.

Comment: @dragoste I didn't knew this function :) Nice to learn about it. Thanks !